# can't pass object variables to the constructor of another class in java

Tags: java, class, constructor, null

I am learning java from core java volume 1 book and very new to java.sorry for confusing title but I don't what is going on. I had written a program which will print the information about a person on a screen. So I had created an array of  object of Man class:-

Here is my Man class:-

```
package com.smit.man;

public class Man
{

    private int age;
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private double weight;

    public Man(int aage,String aname,double aweight,long aid)
    {
        age =aage;
        name = aname;
        weight = aweight;
        id = aid;
    }
   private Add add = new Add((name + "'s Shellter;"),(name + "'s hous's front road;"),(name + " colony;"),id+422);


    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }


    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

        public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }


    /**
     * @return the weight
     */
    public double getWeight()
    {
        return weight;
    }

    public void pall()
    {
        System.out.println
        (
                "Name = " +this.getName() +
                " Age = "+this.getAge() +
                " ID = " +this.getId() +
                " Weight = "+this.getWeight()
        );
        add.pall();
        System.out.println("\n\n\n");
    }

}
```

This Man class Uses the Add class which is this :-

```
package com.smit.man;

/**
 * @author smit
 *
 */
public class Add
{
    private String shellterN,Rd,colony;
    private long pin;

    Add(String a,String b,String c,long d)
    {
        this.shellterN = a;
        this.Rd = b;
        this.colony =c;
        this.pin = d;
    }
    public String getShellterN()
    {
        return shellterN;
    }

    public String getRd()
    {
        return Rd;
    }

    public String getColony()
    {
        return colony;
    }

    public long getPin()
    {
        return pin;
    }

    public void pall()
    {
        System.out.println("ShellterName = " + this.getShellterN() + 
                " Road = "+this.getRd()+ 
                " Colony= "+ this.getColony()+
                " PIN = " + this.getPin());
    }


}
```

And here is main method class:-

```
package com.smit.main;

import com.smit.man.*;

public class Mtest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Man man [] = new Man[3];

        man[0]= new Man(17,"Smit",55,34);
        man[1] = new Man(100,"Master",60,400);
        man[2] = new Man(200,"Guru",10,39);

        for(Man a:man)
            a.pall();

    }

}
```

Whenever I run this in eclipse I get following output

```
Name = Smit Age = 17 ID = 34 Weight = 55.0
ShellterName = null's Shellter; Road = null's hous's front road; Colony= null colony; PIN = 422




Name = Master Age = 100 ID = 400 Weight = 60.0
ShellterName = null's Shellter; Road = null's hous's front road; Colony= null colony; PIN = 422




Name = Guru Age = 200 ID = 39 Weight = 10.0
ShellterName = null's Shellter; Road = null's hous's front road; Colony= null colony; PIN = 422
```

I don't want this null?? Why I am getting this null ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private Add add = new Add((name + "'s Shellter;"),(name + "'s hous's front road;"),(name + " colony;"),id+422);
```

this line is outside of the constructor, so it gets called right when the object is creates (even before the constructor).
You have to make the add to a private variable like all the others and init it at the end of the constructor.

When this line is called, the man's name isn't initialized yet, so it is a null. That's what creates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're creating the `private add` class-level member in the `Man` class *before* the constructor executes.  As soon as the class exists at all, class-level instantiations are executed.  Then the constructor runs.  So the `name` member has its default value at that time.

Instantiate the value in the constructor *after* the `name` value exists:

```
private Add;

public Man(int aage,String aname,double aweight,long aid)
{
    age =aage;
    name = aname;
    weight = aweight;
    id = aid;

    add = new Add((name + "'s Shellter;"),(name + "'s hous's front road;"),(name + " colony;"),id+422);
}
```